# How to perform a graphical solution for an optimization?

Tags: matlab, optimization, plot

I have a very simple problem that can be solved easily on `Matlab` using `fmincon`. But without using `fmincon`, how can I solve it graphically? 
I have tried to plot both optimization function and the constraint function. But I don't know how to interpret it! Please check my code weather I am on the right path.

```
syms myNorm(x,y) const(x,y)

funny(x,y)= sqrt(x^2+y^2);
con = (x/2)^0.75 + (y/3)^0.75 - 1;
fsurf(funny, [0 2 0 3],'FaceColor','b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5)
hold on
fsurf(con, [0 2 0 3],'FaceColor','y', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5)
```

Using fmincon the solution is  `1.0557, 0.8278`.

Comment: I assume the constrain is a logical?  `(x/2)^0.75 + (y/3)^0.75 - 1>0`?

Comment: It's an equality constraint `(x/2)^0.75 + (y/3)^0.75 - 1=0` @AnderBiguri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I dont have MATLAB 2016a, so I can not do this symbolically. I can, instead, do it numerically.

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:0.01:2,0:0.01:3);

funny= sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
con = (abs((x/2).^0.75 + (y/3).^0.75 - 1)<0.01); % numerically will never be ==0
funnycon=funny;
funnycon(~con)=NaN; %if it doesn't match condition, delete

hold on
surf(x,y,funnycon,'linestyle','none','FaceColor','r')
surf(x,y,funny, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5,'linestyle','none')
axis tight;
view(3)

% find the point numerically. We only have 0.01 maximum accuracy (beause
% meshgrid)
funnycon=funny;
funnycon(~con)=Inf;
[~,I]=min(funnycon(:));

minX=x(I);
minY=y(I);

% plot minimum
plot3(minX,minY,funnycon(I),'bo','markersize',5,'markerfacecolor','b')
```

[image]